# How to display images in react native android app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to images to take full width of device screen. I tried multiple CSS code but it doesn't take full width of screen.

Code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Image source={require('./Images/rectangle/rectangle.png')}  style={styles.backgroundImage}>

                    </Image>

                </View>
            </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       flex: 1
    },
    backgroundImage: {
        height: 200,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    }
});
```

Above css doesn't work and I am getting white space on right side of image see screenshot:

[image]

I have also added images with different suffixes so that it will work for different screens see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: you have a <View> surrounding the <Image>  It isn't needed.

Comment: @MikeM I want to ask you. I have added suffixes to images eg: `@2x `, `@3x` etc so it correct way or just adding rectangle.png is sufficient but will it be able to display for small/large screen devices ?

Comment: You can just use rectangle.png.  If you have multiple sized images (e.g., 100x100, 200x200, 300x300), then yes, `@2x` and `@3x` will provide better resolution.  Not sure if `@4x` and `@5x` are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
backgroundImage:{
  width: Dimension.get('window').width ,
  alignSelf: 'center',
  height: 200,
}
```

Comment: @mojtbaba I want to ask if I have added suffixes for images then doesn't it pick the most suitable image which fits the screen ?